# Matrix derivatives, problem with dimensions

Tags: matrices, derivatives, chain-rule

I'm trying to find a derivative of function:
$$L = f \cdot y;  f = X \cdot W + b$$

Matrices shapes: $X.shape=(1, m), W.shape=(m,10), b.shape=(1, 10), y.shape=(10, 1)$
I'm looking for $\frac{\partial L}{\partial W}$

According to chain-rule:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial W} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial f}  \frac{\partial f}{\partial W} $$

Separately we can find:
$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial f}  = y$$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial W} = X$$

And the problem is that the derivative's dimension of $\frac{\partial L}{\partial W} $ according to my formula is $(10, m)$. However, the dimension should coincide with dimension of $W$.

Also I was advised to find differential of $L$:

$$ d(L) = d(f \cdot y) = d(f) \cdot y = d (X \cdot W + b)y = X \cdot dW \cdot y $$
But I do not understand how can I get from this the derivative $\frac{\partial L}{\partial W} $

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a convention where a lowercase Latin letter always represents a **column** vector, an uppercase Latin is a matrix, and a Greek letter is a scalar.

Using this convention your equations are 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= W^Tx + b \cr
\lambda &= f^Ty \cr
}$$
As you have noted, the differential of the scalar function is
$$\eqalign{
d\lambda &= df^Ty = (dW^Tx)^Ty = x^TdW\,y \cr
}$$
Let's develop that a bit further by introducing the Trace function 
$$\eqalign{
d\lambda &= {\rm Tr}(x^TdW\,y) = {\rm Tr}(yx^TdW) \cr
}$$
Then, depending on your preferred [Layout Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions), the gradient is either
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial W} &=yx^T \quad{\rm or}\quad xy^T \cr
}$$
Since you expected the the dimensions of the gradient to be those of $W$, it sounds like your preferred layout is $xy^T$

Also note that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}\neq X.\,$  The gradient is a 3rd order tensor, while $X$ is just a 2nd order tensor (aka a matrix). The presence of these 3rd and 4th order tensors as intermediate quantities in the chain rule can make it difficult/impossible to use in practice.

The differential approach suggested by your advisor is often simpler because the differential of a matrix is just another matrix quantity, which is easy to handle.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it became more clear for me now! I have 2 questions about your solution:
1) Do I understand correctly that you introduced Trace function, because dλ is scalar so const=Tr(const) ? 

2) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}$ is 3rd order tensor. Maybe in this case you know how chain rule works in Neural Networks? Because I get derivative from previous layer and I should multiply it by the derivative of current layer according to chain rule. However, as you mentioned, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}$ now is a 3rd order tensor, so how can we apply chain rule?

Comment: And even if X is matrix then f is also a matrix and we should take a derivative: matrix-by-matrix?

Comment: @DmitryDenisov 1) Yes, ${\rm Tr}(scalar)=scalar,\,$ 2) the gradient really is a 3rd order tensor.  The point is you **never** need to calculate 3rd order (vector-by-matrix) or 4th order (matrix-by-matrix) derivatives, and the programs you write will never calculate such quantities either.  These [online notes](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html) are worth a read.

Comment: In this row 
nabla_w[-1] = np.dot(delta, activations[-2].transpose())
they set $\frac{\partial L}{\partial W}$ is equal to $X^T \cdot \delta$, so it doesn't seem like chain rule.  I.e. in another case they also should calculate the derivative using differential on paper, however they stated that chain rule is a universal approach